# How to call ntoskrnl.exe srand function?

Tags: c++, windows, kernel, driver

With dumpbin.exe, we can see that ntoskrnl.exe exports the srand function.

With the Windows Driver Kit, how to call this function ?

I have already tested with stdlib.h, but I would like to call ntoskrnl.exe directly.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdlib.h>

EXTERN_C NTSTATUS DriverEntry(DRIVER_OBJECT *pDriverObject, UNICODE_STRING *pRegistryPath)
{
    srand(100);
    return STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL;
}
```

Comment: Why not just `#include <stdlib.h>`?   That way you'd see the function is declared as `__cdecl` not `__fastcall`.

Comment: @trojanfoe You are right, this works! I hadn't found Microsoft's documentation for that function for kernel drivers on Google, so I declared it manually. And I assumed that the question is x64 environment and `__fastcall` is what I copied from IDA. I have edited this answer. Thanks!